# Can't connect to Tomcat even though it's running

Tags: tomcat

I've tried to install Apache Tomcat 5.5 and 6 in 2 different ways ([from source](http://www.sizledcore.com/2009/06/how-to-install-and-configure-apache-tomcat-6-on-debian-5/) and [with apt-get](http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-setup-apache-tomcat-55-on-debian-etch.html)) on Debian 5 and Debian 6 -- no success. The server is running but I can't connect to it.

`netstat -a`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN
tcp        0      0 `hostname`:ssh          my_home_ip:4318      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     52 `hostname`:ssh          my_home_ip:remctl    ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8009               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:8180               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*
udp        0      0 *:33059                 *:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*
udp6       0      0 [::]:43829              [::]:*
```

`netstat -tnlp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1416/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      7880/jsvc
tcp6       0      0 :::8180                 :::*                    LISTEN      7880/jsvc
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1416/sshd
```

`ps aux | grep tomcat`:

```
root      7878  0.0  0.0   1984   352 ?        Ss   21:55   0:00 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat55 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat5.5.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat5.5/common/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat5.5 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
root      7879  0.0  0.0   1984   460 ?        S    21:55   0:00 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat55 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat5.5.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat5.5/common/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat5.5 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
tomcat55  7880  0.1  5.3 324068 27932 ?        Sl   21:55   0:01 /usr/bin/jsvc -user tomcat55 -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/tomcat5.5/bin/bootstrap.jar -outfile SYSLOG -errfile SYSLOG -pidfile /var/run/tomcat5.5.pid -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat5.5/common/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat5.5 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat5.5 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/temp -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/catalina.policy -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat5.5/conf/logging.properties org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
root      8013  0.0  0.0   1716   492 pts/0    R+   22:13   0:00 grep tomcat
```

`nmap` port check:

```
# nmap localhost -p 8180
Starting Nmap 4.62 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-03-03
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8180/tcp closed unknown
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.025 seconds

# nmap localhost -p 8009
Starting Nmap 4.62 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-03-03
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
8009/tcp closed ajp13
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.027 seconds

# nmap localhost -p 22
Starting Nmap 4.62 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-03-03
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.026 seconds
```

Catalina log:

```
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: 
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:26 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8180
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 486 ms
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8180
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/24  config=null
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Mar 3, 2012 9:55:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 321 ms
```

`java -version`:

```
java version "1.5.0_22"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)
```

I've also tried force-assigning Tomcat to my VPS external IP. I've been also getting the *Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap.* error from time to time, but I guess that's not the issue since Tomcat is not responding anyway.

Sorry for so much text -- I tried to be informative. Please help me. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**
As stated in the answer, Tomcat was listening on an IPv6 port. In order to change that, I had to add an environment variable for JAVA machine to the `/etc/profile` file

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export JAVA_OPTS
```

... reload the file: `source /etc/profile`

... and then configure Tomcat's main `Connector` by editing the `/etc/tomcat5.5/server.xml` (in my case) in the following way:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
    connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" address="0.0.0.0" />
```

Notice the `address="0.0.0.0"` which tells Tomcat to bind to an IPv4 address.

Thank you for your time, and have a nice day everyone.

Comment: Does the port show as open when you scan `::1` instead of localhost?

Comment: @Shane Madden thanks for your suggestion, you were right: `nmap -6 ::1 -p 8009 PORT STATE SERVICE 8009/tcp open ajp13`. Would you please post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat seems to be listening on only the IPv6 loopback address, `::1`.

Comment: Once again, thank you. Solved the issue by setting `$JAVA_OPTS` in `/etc/profile` to the value of `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` and configuring Tomcat to listen on `address="0.0.0.0"`.

Comment: Not sure why haven't I originally upvoted this back when I accepted the answer 6 years ago :/

Answer (score 1):

It smells like a firewall problem -- try opening up the relevant rules in your firewall (consider just letting everything in/out over `lo`, I've never seen a legitimate case for restricting loopback traffic).

Comment: Thanks, this might be useful for someone else having problem with installing Tomcat.